# How to debug Angular Service which doesn't inject [construct] itself?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services, angular-decorator

I've got a very simply service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MdSnackBar, MdSnackBarConfig } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable()
export class AlertsService {
  alerts: string[];

  constructor(private snackBar: MdSnackBar) {
    this.alerts = [];
  }

  public add(alert: string, action?: string, config?: MdSnackBarConfig) {
    this.alerts.push(alert);
    // console.warn('AlertsService::alerts =', this.alerts, ';');
    this.snackBar.open(alert, action, config);
  }
}
```

…and a module for its dep (`import: [`ed by 'app.module'):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MdSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule, MdSnackBarModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MdSnackBarModule
  ]
})
export class AlertsModule { }
```

The Service is listed in 'app.module':

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SomeComp1Module,
    AlertsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AlertsService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

It's used like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-comp1',
  templateUrl: './some-comp1.component.html'
})
export class SomeComp1Component {
  constructor(private alertsService: AlertsService) {
      this.alertsService.add('SomeComp1Component');
  }
}
```

#### Bug

```
TypeError: this.alerts is undefined
```

Making `alerts` static, then gives me: `TypeError: this.snackBar is undefined`.

[My test-case](https://github.com/AlecTaylor/material-alerts-ng) doesn't replicate the bug. Clearly `AlertsService` isn't being constructed/inject here. **How do I debug the injector?**

Comment: It's unclear what the question is. What is '[construct]'? What do you want to debug it for? *doesn't replicate the bug* - what bug?

Comment: Whoops, edited out that, hold on

Comment: Where is `providers` defined? It is relevant here and it was likely defined the wrong way.

Comment: Edited with my `AppModule`.

Comment: You can debug it with Augury Chrome extension, or by logging or putting a breakpoint on `this.alertsService`, but it looks like it can be solved with regular sanity check here. *Making alerts static, then gives me: TypeError: this.snackBar is undefined* - this suggests that it was defined as `{ provide: AlertsService, useValue: AlertsService }`. If you cannot replicate this in your test case, this means that it was done in one way in one place and in another way in another place.

Comment: Would you like to check as to you would need angular material components in a service?

Comment: so if you put debugger into `constructor(private alertsService: Ale...) {debugger; this.alertsService...}` what is `this.alertsService`?

Comment: `this.alertsService` refers to the `AlertsService` defined above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it in a few different ways:

#### Bind

```
.catch(this.alertsService.add.bind(this.alertsService))
```

Now the `alertsService` actually showed correct output to the rendered browser view.

#### Instance functions

Still was getting `TypeError: this.alerts is undefined` sometimes (from the exact same context `Comp0::func0::this.alertsService`) so decided to try this [other TypeScript recommended solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript):

```
public add = (alert: string, action?: string, config?: MdSnackBarConfig) => {
    this.alerts.push(alert);
    this.snackBar.open(alert, action, config);
}
```

#### Other

This `this` bug was annoying me so much that I regenerated all the code and migrated my original base back in with a 'fine toothed comb'. So not sure if it's related, but I found an extra `BrowserAnimationsModule` import and some missing `rxjs/add` imports.

Comment: And now I can take all `.bind` for `AlertsService` out of my code-base also.